# Is $(0,0)$ in the solution set for this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

I was in my differential equations course and we were covering basic linear systems. We were working through

$\frac{dx}{dt}=x$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=3y$

This yields

$x=Ae^\left(t\right)$ and $y=Be^\left(3t\right)$ where A and B are constants.

If you simplify this, you get

$y=\frac{B}{A^3}x^3$

if I remember correctly. I proceeded to ask whether or not (0,0) is in the solution set since if A,B are non zero, you never reach $x=0$ and $y=0$. See my question is, if you simplify it down to $y=\frac{B}{A^3}x^3$, if you were to plot this function, do you have to put a hole at the origin?

Comment: Hint: How would you solve the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(0,0)$ won't be attained by your solution, if you choose $A\neq 0$ or $B\neq 0$. On the other hand you don't have to do that. It is just done here, so that you can draw a pretty picture in $2$ dimensions of a possible solution orbit.

In summary:
Since $(0,0)$ does not belong to this choosen orbit, you should leave a hole at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question as asking about plotting the solution for a single choice of both $A$ and $B$.  If this is what you mean, you don't just leave a hole at $(0,0)$ because the trajectory can only ever be on one side of $(0,0)$.  The solution trajectories each live in only one quadrant (as specified by the signs of $A$ and $B$).

Example:  Let $A = B = 1$, so $\frac{B}{A^3} = 1$.  Then the trajectory follows $y = x^3$, but ...  $\lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} x(t) = \lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} y(t) = 0$ and for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, your exponential solutions give $x(t) > 0$ and $y(t) > 0$.  This trajectory is only the part of $y = x^3$ in the first quadrant.  (And I mean that precisely : the point at the origin isn't in the first quadrant.)  As you go back in $t$ the parametric solution moves closer to the origin and as you move forward in time, it moves up and right.  So not only do you indicate an open endpoint at $(0,0)$, you don't continue the plot out of the first quadrant.

Example:  Let $A = B = -1$, so $\frac{B}{A^3} = 1$ again.  Then the trajectory follows $y = x^3$, but only in the third quadrant because your exponential solutions give $x(t) < 0$ and $y(t) < 0$.  As you go back in $t$ the parametric solution moves closer to the origin and as you move forward in time, it moves down and left.  So not only do you indicate an open endpoint at $(0,0)$, you don't continue the plot out of the third quadrant.